# Switching ATX PSU with a NPN transistor controlled by a 12V signal

Tags: 12v, atx

I searched everywhere but I can't find a circuit to turn on a PSU with a 12V signal.
I know that PS_ON has an internal pullup but its value may change by vendor.
So I don't know if I can use this circuit: [switch 5V with 12V](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/366141/can-i-switch-npn-transistor-using-12v)
because a user wrote that the base resistor must be calculated with the pullup value.

Thanks

Comment: that will work - the circuit that has the 2n2222 bjt and the 27k resistor on the base. You don't need the 1k pullup resistor as the ATX power supply has that already.

Comment: @Kartman my doubt was about the base resistor because the post I saw use 250mA load but ATX ha a max of 1.6mA. Is it fine anyway this 27k resistor?

Comment: @valepe to switch a max of 1.6mA? 27k should be fine. If it doesn't work, you can try a lower resistance, like 10k. You won't need it though - I see that 2N2222A is specced for a minimum of 50 hFE at very low currents, which by my calculation means even 330k wouldn't be too high.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite… since you are doing pure switching you don't really need to set a 'proper' quiescent point. The 2N2222 can handle a lot of current for this application, in fact.

At 150mA collector has a minimum guaranteed hFE of 100 so with only 1.5mA base drive you'll drive it without issues. I *really* doubt it takes 150mA to turn on the PSU, probably 10-20mA would do the trick anyway.

By the way, the specs for the pin are there: https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/guides/power-supply-design-guide-june.pdf

at page 23 it says that 1.5mA *must* turn on the supply. It's really easy to drive.

Comment: Thank you. Can you help me to the right circuit? Which resistor should I put at the base?

Comment: Consider a typical 0.6V Vbe, so you need to drop 4.4V on the resistor. For about 2mA (which is overkill) put a 2200 ohm resistor. It's really not critical, it would work even with 10k on the base

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works like a charm!

Comment: @LorenzoMarcantonio In the end, I used a 4.7k resistance and a 100k from base to ground just to avoid a floating value when 12V is off.